# Develop a webapp, host it immediately elsewhere while developing/debugging it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets, web-applications

I don't want to open a port at home to develop, while developing with outside services.  What options do I have to develop and host somewhere else?  I usually always develop on localhost, but don't like the idea of opening ports at home.

using java, maven, servlets, eclipse...

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of options out there for developing and deploying.

[Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin) has small amounts of free computing power, and it has a plugin for Maven.

You could also just use a VPS, but you'd have to set up the environment with Java and Maven yourself. Plenty of VPS providers give roots access for cheap, such as Host Gator, DreamHost, or OVH.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey.  I've been looking at Heroku and don't see a way to debug into my code.  Of course a VPS is probably easiest, but it's 20$ / month.  With Heroku, it looks like you can only develop your webapp locally, then when you're happy, deploy it.

Comment: @MikeGagnon That's true. On Heroku you could alternatively [view logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) or [deploy locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local).

Comment: Thought I already accepted this answer, sorry I took so long...  :)